# Qant, Create XTS spread object with bid ask and last data from xts objects

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

i have 3 csv files with last/bid/ask (with volumes) tick data for two instruments (6 files in total), i want to create a spread from these files to be used for backtesting in Quantstrat.

i can get them into xts object and i have looked into the fn_SpreadBuilder. but any suggestions on the way forward would be good.

my strategy needs to act on the bid/ask of the spread.

Comment: This is the format of the data when i import into R

Comment: 2 20150421 180311 61.90 7
3 20150421 180312 61.90 8
4 20150421 180315 61.90 4
5 20150421 180315 61.90 3